Signature decoding error: Encoded text cannot have a 6-bit remainder
My updater doesn't work. I generated keys as it was shown in the updater guide,
but instead on release builds it just gets stuck on installUpdate() phase and when I try to reproduce the issue in debug builds by reducing the version in tauri.conf.json I get this error in js console:
image
And please correct my steps if required, how to generate public and private key and how to use for updater I am follow below steps...

run command: npm run tauri signer generate
after output put public key in tauri.config.json and private key put on environment variable
create build using command: npm run tauri build
upload .msi.zip and .msi.zip.sig on endpoint path
those file getting from path: src-tauri/target/release/bundle/msi/
from old version project run command: npm run tauri dev
Got the above error.

Updater should be work
